# Questions about Sharpe Ratio calculation

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, sharpe-ratio

1. Let's say I have daily returns. Don't they depend on the risk per trade I am using? Obviously, if I'm risking 2% of equity per trade returns will be drastically different than when I'm using 10%? So if I have a strategy I have to assume a certain % risk per trade in order to calculate Sharpe? Wouldn't it be too easy to manipulate Sharpe by just changing this parameter?
2. I'm going to use one of these bad boys for risk-free rate here.

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield

But which one should I use? Given that I'm working with daily returns, not yearly.

3. When inputting daily returns in Sharpe formula should they be compounded or not? Like if I start with \$100 in equity should every daily return be based on \$100 in equity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question1: I think you're confused on what you're actually measuring. Don't think about this in terms of trades, think about it in terms of the total value of your portfolio. At day 1 you have 100 dollars, tomorrow you have 110, 2 days from now 115 and a week from now it's back to 105. How many trades you made during that period, how big those positions are or even how much cash you have is irrelevant. The time series of those portfolio values (100, 110, 115.... 105) is from where you calculate your standard deviation and average return to get your Sharpe Ratio.

Question 2: Even if you're working with daily returns and measure the daily standard deviation it's probably a good idea to transform those into yearly measures (in fact you need to do so in order to calculate your Sharpe ratio). Just take $1-(1+r)^{252}$, where r is your average daily return calculated in question 1, to get your average yearly return and $\sigma_ {daily} * \sqrt{252}$ to get your volatlity as a yearly measure. The interest rates you found are already measured yearly. the correct rate to use is the theoretical risk free rate, so none of them really, but the 10-year rate should be fine for your purposes.

Question 3: Again, not sure what you mean. Do you mean if you should use the geometric or arithmetic mean when finding your average rate of return? I would use the geometric but I'm sure you'll be able to find people with differing opinions.

Comment: 1. 252 for markets that don't trade 365 days a year?

2. by compouning or not I mean difference betwen:

Let's say I make 3% per trade on average. Compunded:

100
103
103*1.03
103*1.03*1.03

not compouned
103
103
103
103

So compounded would change capital base on every new day and calculate return off it. Non-compunded would start with $100 every day.

The daily returns are different in the two cases.

100
103

Comment: Yes, 252 is usually used as the number of trading days in a year

Comment: by compouning or not I mean difference betwen: Let's say I make 3% per trade on average. Compunded: 100 103 103*1.03 103*1.03*1.03 not compouned 103 103 103 103 So compounded would change capital base on every new day and calculate return off it. Non-compunded would start with $100 every day. The daily returns are different for the two cases.

Comment: Sorry it's confusing. I guess best way I can put it is do we change our equity on every new day as it fluctuates up and down with new trades or we start every day with hypothetical $100?

Comment: It doesn't matter. 3% return is 3% return regardless if it's acting on 100 dollars or 200 dollars

Comment: I should clarify for my answer of question 1, you would calculate the mean and standard deviation of your returns each day. So (110/100, 115/110... 105/115) etc. So you don't need to explicitly "normalize" your returns as they already are

Comment: Got it. What about the relationship between the risk I take on each trade and Sharpe? I can influence Sharpe by influencing returns by jacking risk up or down? Or I can't? As I just jack up risk, returns will go up but so will stddev and it will even out somehow and Sharpe will stay same?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean with "risk you take" but essentially yes, that's the entire point of the Sharpe ratio. If you take riskier positions, such as buying equities with a higher volatility, the standard deviation of your portfolio returns will likely also increase (and hopefully so will your returns). The Sharpe ratio won't somehow always stay the same compared to a portfolio with a less risky trading strategy, it can be both smaller or greater, but it will be comparable and you could make the argument that the strategy that results in the larger Sharpe ratio is the better one.

Comment: 1. By risk, I mean the % of equity risked on each trade. And of course that can be levered via leverage too. So that's what I mean. Something along these lines.

2. If low risk stuff like T-bills, etc that are used as RF proxy pay like clockwork 365 days and we're essentially competing vs that rate of return, shouldn't we use 365 rather than 252?

Comment: I see, then yes that will of course impact your Sharpe ratio but it won't manipulate it, my last comment addresses this. I hope you got it. And well no, you get a daily return on the interest like you said for 365 days of the year but only 252 of the days for the equity. If you calculate daily returns for a year straight you will have 252 number of returns, right?

Comment: Disagree with you about 252/365. Since RF is 365 days based, our performance should also be to make a fair comparison. I think it should be 365 and non-trading days should just have 0% returns.


Is the 252 you're suggesting the standard treatment of this issue?

Comment: Multiplying by 252 makes it 365 days based...  You're taking the average of 252 days in a year, so the number you need to scale with is 252 to make it a yearly measure. Yes it's standard treatment

Comment: But risk-free year is 365 days. Our returns year is 252. They need to be the same to compare apples to apples.

Comment: They are the same. 1 year = 1 year. The time it takes for 252 business days to pass is 365 regular days